# Make my enemy move right and then left

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hello flash programmers, 
I am trying to accomplish a way of making my enemy move left a certain amount of pixels, and then when it has, I want it to move the opposite way.
so if the enemy.x += has moved 20 pixels. make it move  the opposite way, and then make it move left.

So you know in platform games, you have enemies that move right and then left. That's what I want to achieve.

But my code does not work for some reason, because the timer does not reset to 0.

May I please have some assistance with the code.

```
    private function goblinLoop(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace(nTimer);

        if (move)
        {
            nTimer = nTimer + 0.05;
            if (nTimer < 5)
            {
                this.x += speed;
            }   
            else
            {
                this.x -= speed;
                if (nTimer > 5)
                {
                    nTimer = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the code, I was testing the if statements and flash go confused so I had to change one thing and this was

```
private function goblinLoop(e:Event):void 
{
    trace(nTimer);

    if (move)
    {
        nTimer = nTimer + 0.05;
        if (nTimer < 5)
        {
            this.x += speed;
        }   
        else
        {
            this.x -= speed;
            if (nTimer > //this can't be 5, it's not logical, so it has to be 10)
            {
                nTimer = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps others, and you can use this to move your characters left and right

if you reckon, there is an efficient way to move left and right, please let me know. Than kyou.